# Communication between two encapsulated components

Tags: c++

I've got three components- a rendering system, a physics simulation, and a UI. The UI code is written in script and is untrusted. Now I need to communicate the results of my physics simulation to the rendering system and am unsure of the correct design. For example, I could simply copy the new sim data over to the renderer every tick. However, this seems like a bit of a waste. I could set the renderer to operate over the sim's data directly, but this seems like it would violate encapsulation.

I am intending this system to work with potentially thousands of moving units, so it is worth keeping performance in mind.

How can I move data from one component to the other quickly without violating encapsulation?

Comment: could you not present the data as const? `sim.cdata()` or something like that?

Comment: Why not do the following: define a (more or less) stable interface on the sim data, and make the renderer get only the interface? The sim's implementation details are going to be hidden this way, right?

Comment: @Vlad: Sure. That'll only be partial encapsulation, rather than total... but I guess it'll live. Consider posting it as an answer.

Comment: @DeadMG: well, that's too weak for an answer for such a non-trivial question. :(

Comment: A bit vague for any serious non-guess answer.

Comment: @CrazyEddie: What more detail would you like to see?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably have the renderer allocate objects to hold the data needed for rendering. Those objects will define a visible interface that's sufficient for the renderer to do its job, but are otherwise opaque. Even though the objects themselves are allocated/owned by the renderer, they're mostly an opaque type to it.

The simulator owns the knowledge of the internals of those objects (at least if more knowledge is needed than is shown by the public interface). Where the renderer basically just reads data from them, the simulator can/will modify their state/write data to them.

One way to implement that is to use multiple inheritance for the "go-between" objects. One of the parents provides the limited public interface for use by the renderer, the other provides the more comprehensive interface for use by the simulator.

Of course, like essentially anything with the protection provided by C++ itself, this is basically only protecting against accident, not intentional subversion. I'm assuming your lack of trust in the renderer is basically protecting against possible bugs, not a renderer that might attempt to intentionally subvert the security. If you need to protect against the latter, you're pretty much looking at a need to at least use OS-level mechanisms such as the simulator and renderer being in separate processes, with some sort of IPC between them (but, of course, that'll almost inevitably add quite a bit of overhead).